# How to convert jira api output to dataframe

Tags: python, jira, jql

I have tried the following script to call jira api to get the jira issues.

```
JQL = 'project = DEMO AND status IN ("To Do", "In Progress") ORDER BY issuekey'
data = jira.jql(JQL)
print(data)
```

However, it is not in table format. How to convert to dataframe with selected columns?